# Move-SPUser: The parameterless Read method can only be used when this instance was initialized with an SPUser object

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, user-profile, user, move

When I try to use the following Powershell command with a user who exists in the User Profile Database I get the following error:

> Move-SPUser : The parameterless Read method can only be used when this
>   instance was initialized with an SPUser object.  At line:1 char:12  +
>   Move-SPUser <<<<  -Identity "OLD_DOMAIN\OLD_USERNAME" -NewAlias
>   "NEW_DOMAIN\NEW_USERNAME"
>        + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...PCmdletMoveUser:
>       SPCmdletMoveUser) [Move-SPUser], InvalidOperationException
>        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletMoveUser

When I attempt to use the following:

`$user = Get-SPUser -web http://my.website.url Identity "OLD_DOMAIN\OLD_USERNAME"`

I get the following error:

> Move-SPUser : At line:1 char:12 + Move-SPUser <<<< -Identity $user -NewAlias > NEW_DOMAIN\NEW_USERNAME + CategoryInfo : InvalidData: >  [Move-SPUser], SPException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : > Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletMoveUser

We have completed a domain migration and are now migrating the end users. I have checked the user profile exists but still seeing this error.

Answer (score 2):

try this way, i am sure it will work.

```
$user = Get-SPUser -web http://my.website.url -Identity "OLD_DOMAIN\OLD_USERNAME"

Move-SPUser -IgnoreSID -Identity $user -NewAlias 'NEW_DOMAIN\NEW_USERNAME'
```

Comment: I tried this and now get an error which seems to be related to the "NEW_DOMAIN\NEW_USERNAME" part of the command.  I updated the question with this information.

Answer (score 1):

I and my co-worker found that it works better when you pipe Get-SPUser into Move-SPUser:

```
Get-SPUser -web http://siteURL -Identity "DomainA\UserA" | Move-SPUser -IgnoreSID -NewAlias "DomainB\UserB"
```